# C++ Check if specific process is running

Tags: c++

I have a C++ DLL that i am writing that needs to check if a particular process is running.

the dll will be launched application will be running in:

```
c:\Directory\application.exe
```

there is a subdirectory within that that has another executable in it:

```
c:\Directory\SubDirectory\application2.exe
```

What the DLL needs to do when it runs if check that application2.exe is running, most importantly that it is running within that folder -- there will be multiple copies running, so we need to ensure that the correct one is running.

I have the following code that is working well at detecting that the application2.exe is running, but it does not take the file path into consideration:

```
HANDLE pss = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPALL, 0);   

PROCESSENTRY32 pe = { 0 };  
pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);  

if (Process32First(pss, &pe))   
{  
 do  
 {  
   if(wcscmp(pe.szExeFile, L"application2.exe") == 0)
   {
       CloseHandle(pss);
       return (1);      
   }
 }  
 while(Process32Next(pss, &pe));  
}   

CloseHandle(pss);
```

How can I check that the path of the process matches the path of the application which called the DLL?

Comment: "Running withing that folder" is an extremely vague condition. There is the notion of a current working directory, do you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI for this.

From the command line you can do:

```
wmic process where "executablepath = 'c:\path\to\executable.exe'" get ProcessId
```

You can use the WMI apis from C++ to do something similar.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C

Comment: did think about using WMI, but it seems a little overkill for this small function

Comment: WMI is powerful but it is slow. There are (usually) faster solutions, such as using "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" for focussed tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have been given a solution that works for this, in case anyone else searching here it is:

```
HANDLE ProcessSnap;
PROCESSENTRY32 Pe32;
unsigned int LoopCounter = 0;

Pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
ProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

Process32First(ProcessSnap, &Pe32);

wchar_t TermPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, TermPath, MAX_PATH);
wstring WTermPath(TermPath);

int index = WTermPath.find(L"\\application.exe");
wstring Path = WTermPath.substr(0, (index));
Path = Path + L"\\SubDirectory\\Application2.exe";

do
{
    HANDLE Process;
    wchar_t FilePath[MAX_PATH];

    Process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, Pe32.th32ProcessID);

    if (Process)
    {
        GetModuleFileNameEx(Process, 0, FilePath, MAX_PATH);
        wstring WFilePath(FilePath);
        if(WFilePath == Path)
        {
            CloseHandle(ProcessSnap);
            return (1);      
        }           
        CloseHandle(Process);
    }

    LoopCounter++;
} while (Process32Next(ProcessSnap, &Pe32));

CloseHandle(ProcessSnap);
```

Comment: Note that this checks whether `Application2.exe` is `SubDirectory\Application2.exe`. Also, it should use `QueryFullProcessImageName ` which is more reliable then `GetModuleFileNameEx` (the module list of a process can change, the EXE can't)

Comment: Or use `GetProcessImageFileName` in combination with `PathCanonicalize`.